# Joining datasets and renaming one column

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I know how to accomplish it but I suppose (or at least I hope to) there is an easier, and less boilerplate, way to do the same.

Scenario:

```
Employee
+-------+---+------------+
|   NAME|AGE|COMPANY_CODE|
+-------+---+------------+
|   John| 41|           1|
|   Mary| 34|           1|
|  Chris| 32|           2|
|Phillip| 22|           2|
|   Tony| 44|           1|
+-------+---+------------+

Company
+----+---------+
|CODE|     NAME|
+----+---------+
|   1|Company-1|
|   2|Company-2|
|   3|Company-3|
+----+---------+
```

My goal is to join both tables by **employee.company_code** **and company_code**, and show employee.name as **NAME**, employee.age as **AGE** and company.name as **COMPANY_NAME** (that is the trick part)

```
// company columns
final Column companyCode = companyDataSet.col("CODE");

// employee columns
final Column employeeCompanyCode = employeeDataSet.col("COMPANY_CODE");

Dataset<Row> join = employeeDataSet.join(companyDataSet, employeeCompanyCode.equalTo(companyCode));

join = join.drop(companyCode).drop(employeeCompanyCode);
```

Printing **join** dataframe, now we get:

```
+-------+---+---------+
|   NAME|AGE|     NAME|
+-------+---+---------+
|   John| 41|Company-1|
|   Mary| 34|Company-1|
|  Chris| 32|Company-2|
|Phillip| 22|Company-2|
|   Tony| 44|Company-1|
+-------+---+---------+
```

I can't use withColumnRenamed method (*join.withColumnRenamed("NAME", "COMPANY_NAME"*) since I have two columns called NAME, and both would be renamed

The only way that I found out to do that is defining all the columns that I want to show up, pass all of them to select dataset method and then to rename the columns as I want to:

```
final Column companyName = companyDataSet.col("NAME");
final Column employeeName = employeeDataSet.col("NAME");
final Column employeeAge = employeeDataSet.col("AGE");

join = join.select(employeeName, employeeAge, companyName.alias("COMPANY_NAME"));

+-------+---+------------+
|   NAME|AGE|COMPANY_NAME|
+-------+---+------------+
|   John| 41|   Company-1|
|   Mary| 34|   Company-1|
|  Chris| 32|   Company-2|
|Phillip| 22|   Company-2|
|   Tony| 44|   Company-1|
+-------+---+------------+
```

In this specific case, it is not a big deal to define all the columns I want to select since they are just a few columns, but imagine in tables with bunches of columns. Defining lots of columns because of one miserable column renaming is too painful.

Any idea how I could avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one simple solution, not as elegante as I think a dataset.withColumnRenamed accepting a Column as first argument would be, but it is better than include all columns just because of one column renaming.

Just rename column NAME from companyDataSet before joining to employeeDataSet:

```
companyDataSet = companyDataSet.withColumnRenamed("NAME", "COMPANY_NAME");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do:

```
join = join.withColumnRenamed(companyDataSet.col("NAME"), "COMPANY_NAME")
```

Would that solve your problem?

Comment: spark-sql_2.11 - 2.3.2 - withColumnRenamed method expects a String (and only a String) as first argument. That's sad! Maybe in new versions it has overloaded version for columns.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be register them as temp tables and write a SQL?

```
employee.createOrReplaceTempView(emp)
company.createOrReplaceTempView(comp)

spark.sql("select t1.Name as Name, t1.Age as Age, t2.Name as Company_Name
        from 
        emp t1 join comp t2
        on
        t1.id = t2.id")
```

Comment: As I said I don't want to type all column names just to rename one of them.